# Angularjs - Using directive to instantiate other directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So lets say in my HTML I have something like this:

```
<tabcontent></tabcontent>
```

Then the javascript for this directive is this:

```
tabsApp.directive('tabcontent', function(){

  var myObj = {
    priority:0,
    template:'<div></div>',
    replace: true,
    controller: 'TabCtrl',
    transclude: false,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    compile: function (element, attrs){
      return function (parentScope, instanceEle){
        parentScope.$watch('type', function(val) {
          element.html('<div '+val+'></div>');
        });
      }
      $compile(parentScope);
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs){}
  };
  return myObj;

});
```

The HTML is parsed properly, and the value for type is found in the controller JS.

```
so <tabcontent></tabcontent> is replaced with <div recipe></div> for example..
```

(that part does happen properly)

So I also have a directive for recipe:

```
tabsApp.directive('recipe', function(){

  var myObj = {
    priority:0,
    template:'<div>TESTING</div>',
    replace: true,
    controller: 'TabCtrl',
    transclude: false,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    compile: function (element, attrs){
      return {
        pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller){},
        post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller){}
      }
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs){}
  };
  return myObj;

});
```

Which is obviously pretty simple, and just for testing. But the recipe directive is not being processed...

Whats going on here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to change 2 things:

1. The `recipe` directive must not be restricted to **E** (element). If you are generating the directive like `<div recipe></div>`, you must at least add **A** (attribute) to the `restrict` property on the directive configuration:

   ```
   app.directive('recipe', function() {
      return {
         restrict: 'E',
         ...
   ```
2. You need to compile the HTML content of the `tabcontent` directive after the 'watch':

   ```
   app.directive('tabcontent', function($compile){
      return {    
      ...    
      link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
               scope.$watch('type', function(val) {
                  iElement.html('<div '+val+'></div>');           
                  $compile(iElement.contents())(scope);         
                });
            }
      ...
   ```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/n2BXp/